# spring batch run a task only once for ever

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a spring batch job. The first task in the job is to create dummy data. I want to run this job only once, it does not matter how many times the job is run after that or let say be able to configure this task to run only once based on some property value in properties file. How do i achieve this functionality.

In production system, this could be same as creating the folder structures to copy different file types before processing the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tasklet](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/tasklet/Tasklet.html) interface of Spring Batch is what you are looking for. You must implement the `execute` method.

```
public class FolderTasklet implements Tasklet{

    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
    //your copy folder structure logic goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using a tasklet right now and as per the official docs, looks like that is suppose to be used for setting up resource and clean up. What I was looking for is to do something one time only no matter how many time a job is run. I guess that sort of thing needs to be done outside the job and then run the job. Thanks for the response

Comment: Spring batch jobs are mostly suitable for reader/writer scenarios. If you need a setup before the main steps in every job execution, you may create it as parent step. But if you need this setup procedure only once, the best thing would be create another job with a tasklet.